# how to use Jprofiler as maven plugin?

Tags: maven, jmeter, jprofiler

Is there a way to set jprofiler as a maven plugin? 
How to integrate jmeter with jprofiler?

Answer (score 0):

As of JProfiler 10.0 there is no maven plugin. You can use the [JProfiler ant task](https://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/offline/ant.html) in maven with the [maven-antrun-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-ant.html):